# How to add Google's Guava to eclipse so I can read the source code

Tags: eclipse, guava

I can add the guava-18.0.jar to my project, yet it is only binary code.

I want to read the source code by ctrl+click. Thanks!

Comment: +1 for the ctlr_click. I didn't know that one :-D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the [**sources**](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=com/google/guava/guava/18.0/guava-18.0-sources.jar) and [**javadoc**](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=com/google/guava/guava/18.0/guava-18.0-javadoc.jar) jars [**here**](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/Release18)

you may also want to create a user library with the three jars

- Go to [Window] → [Preferences] → [Java] → [Build Path] → [User Libraries]
- Click [New] and type the name of the library, say Guava18 → click OK
- Click [Add External Jar] then locate the jar.
- Then you can edit the [Source attachment] and [Javadoc location]

After that, from your project, in the build configuration dialog, [Add Library] → [User Library]. Select the Guava library.